# Normality assumption of structural shocks in Vector Autoregression model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normality-assumption, vector-autoregression, finance

I’m currently working on forecasting yield curve evolution over time using a state space model where the transition dynamics are described using a vector autoregressive model of order 1. This model assumes normally distributed structural shocks, as such this assumption drives the dispersion of outcomes to follow a normal distribution. However, a stylized fact about financial series, including bond yields, is that they exhibit fat tailed distributions. My question is whether this invalidates the use of a $VAR(1)$ model with $\epsilon \sim N(0, \Sigma)$. If so, any suggestions on how a fat tailed distribution can be incorporated using this or a similar approach. Many thanks.